# Ubuntu 14.10 slow shut down after sleep

Tags: shutdown, 14.10, modem-manager

I upgraded from 14.04 to 14.10 recently. The laptop does not shut down properly anymore. It used to take only 3-5 sec to shutdown in 14.04. But now it needs ca. 5 min to shut down after sleep. If it never slept, then shut down process is normal. The message on the shut down screen has something to do with ModemManager:

ModemManager:   ModemManager is shut down

ModemManager:  Could not acquire the 'org.freedesktop.ModemManager1' service name

it stays like that for ca. 5 min before it suddenly shuts down.

I added stop on runlevel [06] to the network-manager.conf file. It did not help. 
I used shutdown -h now. It did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by editing both `/etc/init/modemmanager.conf` and `/etc/init/network-manager.conf` via [adding a line to them](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/10/speed-up-ubuntu-shutdown-process/):

```
kill timeout 1
```